# Trouble installing postgresql on osx using homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I'm trying to install postgres on a new machine for the time. I initially ran thoughtbot's [laptop](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) script to install most of what I'd need for rails development which should have included the postgres installation. Yet when I run a `rake db:create` for the new rails app I get the following error:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "username"=>"riskpool", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"riskpool_development"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling postgres via homebrew like this and this is the result:

```
$ brew remove postgres                                                                                                                       
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2... (3021 files, 40M)
```

And reinstalling postgres

```
$ brew install postgres
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/postgresql-9.4.5_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.4.5_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring postgresql-9.4.5_2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall postgresql`
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.4) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html

To load postgresql:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

WARNING: launchctl will fail when run under tmux.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2: 3021 files, 40M

$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist                                                                      
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation not permitted
```

if I run the second command

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
```

If I try to find out where postgres is installed:

```
$ which postgres
/usr/local/bin/postgres
```

Someone suggested I kill an existing process id that might be interfering:

```
$ rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid                                                                                                   
rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

But I get the same error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: As you are on Mac OSX, make sure your database.yml file inside config folder has no more lines that the ones this file came with, so do not specify a username neither a password. By default it will be you user from the system. See this page in the section [Important Note About Authentication for postgres on mac](http://www.russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x)

Comment: @JuanM. why because on Mac OSX? Does postgres on linux have different defaults for username and password?

Comment: I didn't try on linux, but if you were on windows you would be in the configuration hell for postgres to be running. In windows you have to do some other configurations, like using the software provided by postgres to create users and permissions and other stuff. In mac it's just as simple as to create the app with the `... -d postgresql` option and will work with no trouble. Your problem is not the installation I think, but the creation of database for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this command :

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

It appears that this file is blocking postgres from starting up and it would be the reason why you get the below error :

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Edited the post to reflect my trying this. Didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching the server with root privileges ? i.e.

```
sudo postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

It seems though as the server is not launching due to file permission privileges.
It also seems that the brew postinstall scripts failed, so you may need to initialize the db cluster.
You can use initdb to create a new cluster.

```
sudo initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.4
```

Alternatively, if this is for a development machine, I would recommend just using the postgres app for macosx (simple click and run):
http://postgresapp.com/